# Function 'glWindowPos2i' could not be resolved?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, gcc, glew

While trying to compile a simple example openGL example to display text, I ran into the problem with 'glWindowPos2i' could not be resolved. glWindowPos2i seemed to compile fine as a C program under GCC, but for a could not be resolved error under eclipse as a c++ program with g++. (solution below)

The environment is eclipse (juno) under ubuntu 13.04 with openGL 3.3.0 (NVIDIA 310.44) GLEW version 1.8.0

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that glWindowPos2i is an extension and in order compile with c++, glWindowPos2i needed to be defined by its address. At the top of the program, just after the includes glWindowPos2i needs to be defined as a global.

```
PFNGLWINDOWPOS2IPROC glWindowPos2i;
```

Then in the body of the program, after the glutInit, a value needs to be assigned to the global variable.

```
glWindowPos2i =  (PFNGLWINDOWPOS2IPROC) glutGetProcAddress("glWindowPos2i");
```

The glutGetProcAddress is defined by an include for  and the definition for PFNGLWINDOWPOS2IPROC comes from

The full list of the includes I'm using are

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut_ext.h>
```

The linker includes I'm using are

```
-lGL -lm -lglut -lGLEW -lGLU
```

Comment: You're using GLEW, yet it did not load this extension? I think there are bigger issues at hand if this is the case, as I recall this extension is about 11 years old.

Comment: Be aware that if you are using a core profile context, then this function is technically invalid. It could be that your driver is not providing this in the list of extensions because of that, but for whatever reason if you get the function pointer it still gives you one.

Comment: It beats the heck out of me, but after 2 days of trying to get it to work, I thought I should share my solution. If there is a better one, I'd sure like to know. When I do a 'glewinfo' I get a'glWindowPos2i: OK'. If I restart Eclipse, the program compiles, only to crash when it hits the glWindowPos2i with a 0x0. Without the fix and deleting the -lGLEW, I get a undefined reference to `__glewWindowPos2i', so the linker sees the link but fails to resolve it.

Comment: Are you using a core profile context? I have to imagine the extension string is not showing up at run-time because you are using OpenGL 3.2 core instead of OpenGL 3.2 compatibility.

Comment: I'm guess using the core context. I tried adding      glutInitContextVersion (3, 3); and glutInitContextFlags (GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE );, but the error remained and the program crashed with a 0x0 at the glWindowPos2i call.

Comment: Maybe add #define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES before importing glut.h? It worked for me.